# How do i prevent further burn once the minimum total supply of my token has been reached?

Tags: web3js, remix, erc-20, ethereumj, remix-tests

I have successfully created my token and I have an automatic burn fee but I would like the burn fee to be automatically set to 0 once the minimum total supply has been reached and also  prevent any further manual burn as the token is a very low supply token and I need only the minimum total supply in circulation after burning the allocation for burn.

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming you’re programming one solidity, your `burn` function should use a `require` to ensure `currentTotalSupply !<= minimumTotalSupply`

Comment: Yes, in solidity.